# Sitecore login page returns 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied after HTTPS is enabled

Tags: security, login, amazon-web-services

After enabling HTTPS on a Sitecore website that is hosted on the AWS cloud, we are unable to access the Sitecore login page. https://www.[domainname].com/sitecore which returns 403 - Forbidden:Access is denied error. Some of the other pages do not load their contents as well. How can I resolved the access issue to the Sitecore Login page on Sitecore client?

Comment: you can verify settings https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/restrict_access_to_the_client

Comment: You can check the IIS settings and app pool access and bindings to your instance. If you have `http` instead of `https` in your configurations in IIS, that may have caused the issue. Please share the log or any reference causing that issue and which Sitecore version you are using. P.S I can not comment yet, so replying as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that I couldn't get access to the Sitecore Login page was that setting up HTTPS through Amazon load balancer placed the CMS behind the load balancer gate as well. I didn't add the IP of the load balancer's gate to the white listed IPs, and I wouldn't do such a thing as it would expose the login page to everyone. Ultimately I scrapped this approach and used a purchased certificate to enable the HTTPS.